# Black line appears below screenshot when I paste it into Word

Tags: screen-capture

When I use the screen capture feature on a Mac desktop running Mojave 10.14.6 and then paste the screenshot into Word 2016 for Mac, a black line appears below the screenshot. I'm not using the shadows/3-d elements in the screen capture. I don't want the black line to appear.  Not sure if it's happening with the screen capture, or if Word is adding it.

Comment: Have you tried cmnd&shift&4 for a selection of the screen - works for me..

Answer (score 4):

Please make sure the 'underline'is not turned ON/active in Home Tab. When you paste a picture in a line or paragraph where underline is turned ON/active, then there will be an underline appearing below the picture as well. Just turn off underline after selecting the picture. Hope this helps. !

Comment: Thank you - it was driving my wife mad!

Answer (score 1):

I just found another post regarding Word. If I change the "wrap text" setting in the picture properties to "Square", the black line disappears.

Comment: Are you pasting on a line with underline formatting?